# Is GTK tightly bounded by GCC version?

Tags: linux, firefox, gcc

I want to upgrade firefox version from 30 to 56 on my server which is having OS Linux 2.6(gcc 4.4.7), the problem is, this configuration is supporting only GTK2, but the firefox 56 version requires GTK3.4+, so is there anyway by which I can install GTK3.4 package without upgrading my GCC version?

Answer (score 0):

Gcc will only be a build dependency not a runtime dependency. You should never require a particular gcc version to do an install. If you do have to build, you are free to get a new compiler build and revert, though there are caveats.

What is important; however, is the libc version that gets built in (it's worse with c++ and libstdc++) and it is these lower level ones that are meant to be forward/backward compatible but in reality often are not.

If you want more info, please provide the particular distro (for determining binary package dependencies).